# getting error while uing help command for botium dialogflow connector

Tags: ubuntu, npm, automation, chatbot

getting error while using --help command for botium dialogflow connector

Installed dialogflow connector, botium-bindings in ubuntu
command : npm install botium-connector-dialogflow

tried below command which throws the error
botium-connector-dialogflow-cli dialogflowimport --help

Error :

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:638
    throw err;
    ^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mkdirp'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:690:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/lib/node_modules/botium-connector- 
dialogflow/src/helpers.js:4:16)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:776:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js 
(internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:787:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Comment: This is clearly a bug, I added it to our backlog. As an intermediary solution, please install the mkdirp package manually: "npm install mkdirp" or "npm install -g mkdirp"

Comment: Thank you..Florian. I have used suggested command and its working now.